# JavaScript - Append a css tag to a certain part of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay, so let's say I have a textbox that you can enter something like

```
Sebastian Soria 3'|12' Digano
Nam Tae-Hee 23', 45'|33' Julio Vezbek
```

And that textarea does this upon focusing your mouse out of it, the texarea gets read line by line and each line looks for its delimeter "|" and then splits it up and divides that in home and away scorer.

Here's a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cu24k/

I could easily do it so if it's above 10, to scrap the last 4 characters of " XX'" and 3 do " X'" and split that up and color/bold it. But then I realized, what if they scored more than once? It would be `23', 45'` or longer!

So, I thought... what if I can just take apart any apostrophe, comma and number and color/bold that.

Is there a way?

Comment: `scrap the last 4 characters of " XX'" and 3 do " X'" and split that up and color/bold it` Could you try to rephrase this? Or show it being done in your fiddle? I can't be the only one who doesn't understand what you're trying to say there.

Comment: Since home array would be something like `Testing '4` then I could take the `'4` by taking the last -3 using `substr` of the string or -4 if it was it was more than 9 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you were trying to do, but I threw together what I *think* you were going for: http://jsfiddle.net/cu24k/1/

Here is the updated JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.scorers').on('change', function () {

         $("#home_scorers").text("");
         $("#away_scorers").text("");

         var lines = $('.scorers').val().split('\n');
         for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
             var split      = lines[i].split('|');
             // get home data
             var home       = split[0];
             var homeIndex  = home.search( /\d+\'/ );
             var homeTeam   = home.substr( 0, homeIndex );
             var homeScore  = home.substr( homeIndex );
             // get away data
             var away       = split[1];
             var awayIndex  = away.lastIndexOf( "'" ) + 1;
             var awayScore   = away.substr( 0, awayIndex );
             var awayTeam  = away.substr( awayIndex );
             // output data
             $("#home_scorers").append(
                 "<div>" + homeTeam +
                 "<b>" + homeScore + "</b>" +
                 "</div>");
             $("#away_scorers").append(
                 "<div>" +
                 "<b>" + awayScore + "</b>" +
                  awayTeam + "</div>");
         }

     });

 });
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Do you mind explaining this? From what I see you plit it up and searched individually for ', 0-9 and commas and... from there you took those apart.. and did things.. Hmm

Comment: Sure.  Since the order is different, I had to separately handle home and away.  For home, I searched for the first instance of ##', allowing 1+ digits followed by '.

For the away team, I searched for the last index of a ' to find where it switched from scores to team name.